# Pagination no longer works in Super Search after EE 2.8 upgrade

Tags: solspace, supersearch, 2.8

Here's an error I am receiving on search results after updating to EE 2.8.1:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Pagination_object::get_template()
in /Users/username/Documents/Projects/myproject/system/expressionengine/third_party/super_search/mod.super_search.php 
on line 1161
```

I realize Solspace hasn't confirmed compatibility yet, but if anyone has any workarounds for now that would be great!

Comment: I'm having this same issue but with Calendar. Any Update on this?

Answer (score 1):

replace :

```
$this->EE->pagination->get_template();
```

with:

```
$this->EE->TMPL->tagdata = $this->EE->pagination->prepare($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata);
```

**Updates:**

I don't use Super search before, I just tell you what you must change. 
if you use `$channel->pagination->get_template()` then change it to `$channel->pagination->prepare`

and if just use the same prefix for `->TMPL->tagdata`

Regard's.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The code in question is: `$channel->pagination->get_template()`

Comment: check the updates